# Blue-imp file-upload delete from database with additional variable

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I'm using Blue-imp file-upload to upload files everything seems to be working great with one expception.  I users data being saved to user directories based on their userId but when I try to delete the data from the database it deletes by $name variable, which is the filename.

That means all users with the a file with the same filename are being deleted from the database.  How can I set the delete in my uploadHander.php file to delete by name and userId? Or by the insert id?

class CustomUploadHandler extends UploadHandler {

```
protected function handle_form_data($file, $index) {
    $file->description = $_REQUEST['description'][$index];
    $file->userId = $_REQUEST['userId'][$index];
    $file->location = $_REQUEST['location'][$index];
    $file->customId = $_REQUEST['customId'][$index];
}

protected function handle_file_upload($uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error,
    $index = null, $content_range = null) {
    $file = parent::handle_file_upload(
    $uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error, $index, $content_range
    );


    if (empty($file->error)) {

        $sql = 'INSERT INTO `'.$this->options['db_table']
            .'` (`name`, `size`, `type`, `userId`, `description`,`location`,`customId`,`url`)'
            .' VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?,?)';
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $query->bind_param(
            'sissssss',
            $file->name,
            $file->size,
            $file->type,
            $file->userId,
            $file->description,
            $file->location,
            $file->customId,
            $file->url
        );
        $query->execute();
        $file->id = $this->db->insert_id;

    }
    return $file;
}

protected function set_additional_file_properties($file) {
    parent::set_additional_file_properties($file);
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
        $sql = 'SELECT  `type`, `description`,`location`,`userId`,`customId`,`url` FROM `'
            .$this->options['db_table'].'` WHERE `name`=? and `id`=?';
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $query->bind_param('ss', $file->name,$file->id);
        $query->execute();
        $query->bind_result(
            $type,
            $description,
            $location,
            $userId,
            $customId,
            $url

        );
        while ($query->fetch()) {
             $file->type = $type;
             $file->description = $description;
             $file->location = $location;
             $file->userId = $userId;
             $file->customId=$customId;
             $file->url=$url;

        }
    }
}

public function delete($print_response = true) {
    $response = parent::delete(false);
    foreach ($response as $name => $deleted) {
        if ($deleted) {
            $sql = 'DELETE FROM `'.$this->options['db_table'].'` WHERE `name`=? AND `id`=?';
            $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $query->bind_param('ss',$name,$id);


            $query->execute();

        }
    } 
    return $this->generate_response($response, $print_response);
}
```

}

$upload_handler = new CustomUploadHandler($options);

Comment: Use a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I had this: but it does not delete anything when I include the id

Comment: The id may be lost or not defined somewhere or out of scope. Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and check for errors. Replace `$query->execute();` with `if(!$query->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$this->db->error, E_USER_WARNING);}` see if it yields anything.

Comment: No errors. I am wondering if it could be something like it is not retrieving the insert id?

Comment: It very well could. Where and how is `$id` defined?

Comment: I added the full custom handler.  I am going crazy.  I know it something easy.

Answer (score 0):

I found one error in your code

```
$query->bind_param('ss',$name,$id);
```

Use

```
query->bind_param('si',$name,$id);
```

$id is an integer and you were defining it by string.

Hope this will work for you.

Use this code ==>

```
public function delete($print_response = true) { 
    $response = parent::delete(false);
    foreach ($response as $name => $deleted) {
        if ($deleted) {
            $sql = 'DELETE FROM `'.$this->options['db_table'].'` WHERE `name`=? AND `id`=?';
            $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $query->bind_param('si',$name,$id);
            $query->execute();
        }
    } 
    return $this->generate_response($response, $print_response);
}
```